# Múltiplos modal bootstrap retornando sempre o mesmo conteúdo

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação asp.net mvc, em uma das páginas do site chamo diversos modals do bootstrap um por cima do outro, no entanto, quando já se tem um modal aberto o novo aparece com o mesmo conteúdo do antigo, segue trechos do código.

```
$('#menuLista').click(function () {
    //$('.modal-container').removeData('bs.modal');
    $.get('@Url.Action("MenuListas")',
    { idE: '@ViewBag.idEvento' },
    function (data) {
        $('#fecharModalEv').click();
        $('#modalMnLista').find('.modal-content:first').html(data);
        $('#modalMnLista').modal({ show: true });
    }).error(function () {
        alert('ocorreu um erro ao abrir  janela');
    });

    $.get(url, function (data) {
        $('.modal-content').html(data);
        $('#modal-container').modal('show');
    });             
}

<div id="modal-container" class="modal fade"
         tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="modalMnLista" class="modal fade"
         tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Colei uns trechos aqui mesmo não contendo as tags script, etc.

Uso o Ajax do jquery para retornar partialViews dentro do modal, na primeira chamada preencho a div 'modal-container', já na segunda preencho a 'ModalMnLista'.

Alguém saberia o motivo para o código estar vindo igual na execução de 2 GETs retornando conteúdos diferentes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você está aplicando html em todos os divs com o class `.modal-content` no seu segundo ajax: `$('.modal-content').html(data);`

Tente trocar

```
$('.modal-content').html(data);
```

por

```
$('#modal-container').find('.modal-content:first').html(data);
```

no seu segundo get ajax.